# Linux:How to list the information about file or directory(size,permission,number of files by type?) in total

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Suppose I am staying in currenty directory, I wanted to list all the files in total numbers, as well as the size, permission, and also the number of files by types.

here is the sample outputs:

Here is a sample :

Print information about "/home/user/poker"

total number of file :  83

pdf files : 5

html files : 9

text files : 15

unknown : 5

NB: anyfile without extension could be consider as unknown.

i hope to use some simple command like ls, cut, sort, unique ,(just examples) put each different extension in file and using wc -l to count number of lines

or do i need to use grep, awk , or something else?

Hope to get the everybody's advices.thank you!

Comment: "anyfile without extension could be consider as unknown." This is funny due to the fact that UNIX (Linux) does not use file endings at all.

Comment: For the record, you might also, or instead, want to look at `file`, which guesses a file's type based on its contents.

Answer (score 3):

#### Best way is to use `file` to output only mimetype and pass it to `awk`.

```
file * -ib | awk -F'[;/.]' '{print $(NF-1)}' | sort -n | uniq -c
```

On my home directory it produces this output.

```
 35 directory
  3 html
  1 jpeg
  1 octet-stream
  1 pdf
 32 plain
  5 png
  1 spreadsheet
  7 symlink
  1 text
  1 x-c++
  3 x-empty
  1 xml
  2 x-ms-asf
  4 x-shellscript
  1 x-shockwave-flash
```

#### If you think `text/x-c++` and `text/plain` should be in same Use this

```
 file * -ib | awk -F'[;/.]' '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq -c

  6 application
  6 image
 45 inode
 40 text
  2 video
```

Change the `{print $1}` part according to your need to get the appropriate output.

Answer (score 0):

You need [bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html).

```
files=(*)
pdfs=(*.pdf)

echo "${#files[@]}"
echo "${#pdfs[@]}"
echo "$((${#files[@]}-${#pdfs[@]}))"
```

Comment: suppose you do not know what exact file extension name, the directory  has,, how you can define?

Comment: we don't know the directory has what kinds of file(*.*),how to calculate the files number by types?

Answer (score 0):

`find . -type f | xargs -n1 basename | fgrep . | sed 's/.*\.//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`

That gives you a recursive list of file extensions.  If you want only the current directory add a `-maxdepth 1` to the find command.